# Assets Images in Low Variables not showing across MSM sites

Tags: assets, multi-site-manager, low-variables

Having a small problem with images from an Assets fieldtype ... that is in a Matrix field ... that is in a Low Variable ... showing on a second MSM site.

All the other Matrix fields (basic text fields) list okay ... it's just that the Assets field that is not showing.

So on the second 'MSM' site I've got the following code:

```
{exp:low_variables:pair var="site_1:lv_sites"}
    <p>{image}</p>
    <p>{description}</p>
{/exp:low_variables:pair}
```

If I put the same code on "site_1" the {image} tag comes out fine. On "site_2" the {image} tag comes out blank.  I've tried using {image:server_path} and {image:url} and it's still coming out blank.

Running EE 2.5.5, Assets 2.1.3 and Low Variables 2.3.4.

Any thoughts are welcome!

Cheers.

Comment: Does adding the parameter `site="site_1"` (so Matrix knows it needs to pull data from a different site too) help at all?

Comment: Hmm. Good thought, but didn't seem to make any difference. I do think it's an issue with the site name/id in the Assets field.

Comment: Check the output profiler and look up and DB queries that target the Assets table. Can you see a site_id in the where clause?

Comment: Strange, but it's finding the item in the Assets table fine (I copied and pasted the SQL into Sequel Pro and it ran fine) - SELECT * FROM (`exp_assets_files`) WHERE `file_id` =  '21';
SELECT DISTINCT a.* FROM exp_assets_files AS a INNER JOIN exp_assets_folders AS af ON af.folder_id = a.folder_id INNER JOIN exp_assets_selections AS ae ON ae.file_id = a.file_id WHERE ae.var_id = 16 AND ae.col_id = "23" AND ae.row_id = "95" AND ae.is_draft = 0 ORDER BY ae.sort_order

Comment: Looking at just the output of the profiler, it's listing "Returning No Results Content" for what I think is the 5 {image}{url}{/image} tags I'm testing with in the LV parse tag. WEIRD!

Comment: Andrew, I'm troubleshooting a straight EE/MSM/Assets issue where calling Assets on any one site works, but with multiple sites piped doesn't.  Does that sound familiar to your case?

Comment: Hey Lisa (and Low!) ... yes ... that is happening as well in a normal Channels Entry tag, but essentially the same thing is happening with using Low Variables. I've just tested having a single Assets field in Low Variables on Site1. I then call that field in Site2 ... but nothing shows (tried URL, Server Path, etc). The LV code is simply: {exp:low_variables:parse var="site_1:lv_assets_test" site="site_1"}{server_path}{/exp:low_variables:parse}

Comment: Hey, Andrew.

is it possible to send CP and FTP access to support@pixelandtonic.com so we can look into this?

Thanks!
Andris